# sql - select from many to retrieve data in horizontal, data of one table as columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

- I have table T1 (idT1, Name)
- I have table T2 (idT2, OptionDescription)
- finally I have table T3 (idT3, T1Id, T2Id, Selected)

Suppose to have in T1:

```
idT1    Name
1       John
2       Mary
3       Bill
```

and in T2

```
idT2    OptionDescription
1       "Available On Monday"
2       "Available On Tuesdey"
3       "Available all Nights"
```

and in T3

```
idT3    T1Id    T2Id    Selected
1       1       1       True
2       1       2       True
3       1       3       False
4       2       1       False
5       2       2       False
6       2       3       True
```

Is it possible to write a query that retrieve the data of T1 and T2/T3 in "horizontal" way (I mean with the description of T2 as Column result) like:

```
idT1    Name    "Available On Monday"   "Available On Tuesdey"  "Available all Nights"
1       John    True                    True                    False
2       Mary    False                   False                   True
```

Comment: You are looking for a pivot query, which question has been answered innumerable times on Stack Overflow.  Have you tried something yourself yet?

Comment: no, i did not use pivot query before (don't know what is it, I'll study it now), I will give it a try and search in other answers meantime to find something fitting the question...

Answer (score 0):

Use Pivot

```
Select * from 
(
select t1.idT1,t1.Name,t2.OptionDescription,selected from t1 
 inner join t3 on t1.idT1=t3.idT2
 inner join t2 on t2.idT2=t3.idT3
)x
pivot
(
max(selected)
FOR x.OptionDescription in ([Available On Monday],[Available On Tuesdey],[Available all Nights])
) pvt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @T1 TABLE (idT1 INT,   Name VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES
(1, 'John'),
(2, 'Mary'),
(3, 'Bill');
DECLARE @T2 TABLE (idT2 INT,  OptionDescription VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @T2 VALUES
(1, 'Available On Monday'),
(2, 'Available On Tuesdey'),
(3, 'Available all Nights');
DECLARE @T3 TABLE (idT3 INT,   T1Id INT, T2Id INT, Selected VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @T3 VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 'True'),
(2, 1, 2, 'True'),
(3, 1, 3, 'False'),
(4, 2, 1, 'False'),
(5, 2, 2, 'False'),
(6, 2, 3, 'True');

-- THE QUERY USING CTE -- NOTE YOU MUST NOT USE CTE
; WITH CTE AS 
(
SELECT 
T1.idT1,
T1.Name,
T2.OptionDescription,
T3.Selected
FROM @T3 AS T3
INNER JOIN @T1 AS T1 ON T3.T1Id=T1.idT1
INNER JOIN @T2 AS T2 ON T3.T2Id=T2.idT2

)
SELECT * FROM CTE
PIVOT
(
MAX(selected) FOR OptionDescription IN ([Available On Monday],[Available On Tuesdey],[Available all Nights])
) AS PV1
```

Answer (score 0):

select *
from 
(
 select x.IdT1,x.Name,t2.OptionDescription,x.selected from
 (select t1.IdT1,t1.Name,t3.T2Id,t3.Selected from t1 join t3 on 
  t1.idT1=t3.T1Id)x 
  join T2 on x.T2Id=t2.IdT2
) src
pivot
(
  max(selected)
  for OptionDescription in ([Available On Monday], [Available On Tuesdey], [Available all Nights])
) piv;